# Put SQL query inside case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to put

```
SELECT DISTINCT ResidentGroup 
FROM Credits.ProductsPurposesBalanceGroups 
WHERE BalanceTypeID = 1`
```

inside a `case` expression because table `Credits.ProductsPurposesBalanceGroups` always changes and I need to check for compliance.

When I run the code below in this way, I get this error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

How can avoid this or maybe there is another way to do it?

```sql
select 
    p.TypeName as 'Purpose', 
    sum((case 
            when tr.CurrencyID = 417 
                 and acc_credit.BalanceGroup in (select distinct ResidentGroup 
                                                 from Credits.ProductsPurposesBalanceGroups 
                                                 where BalanceTypeID = 1) 
               then tr.SumV 
               else 0 
         end)) as 'Pay417', 
    sum((case 
            when tr.CurrencyID = 840 
                 and acc_credit.BalanceGroup in (select distinct ResidentGroup 
                                                 from Credits.ProductsPurposesBalanceGroups 
                                                 where BalanceTypeID = 2) 
               then tr.SumV 
               else 0 
         end)) as 'Pay840', 
      -- and it goes that way until BalanceTypeID = 16"""

from 
    dbo.Transactions as tr 
inner join  
    dbo.Accounts as acc_credit on (tr.CreditAccountID = acc_credit.AccountNo)
group by 
    p.TypeName 
order by 
    p.TypeName
```

Comment: `CASE` **expression** *not* a statement. T-SQL does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements, only `CASE` expressions.

Comment: Instead of performing (or better: trying to perform) this query over and over again, I would suggest to move the subquery `SELECT DISTINCT ResidentGroup, BalanyceType...` to a cte, then perform a`LEFT JOIN` to this cte and modify your query to `CASE WHEN [colname] IS NULL THEN 0 else [value] end`...

Comment: Look this https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/251671/187972

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of "compliance" would really help.  I really have no idea what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The following might solve the problem. However, withou any sample data etc. it's hard to evaluate...

```
WITH cteResGrp AS(
  SELECT DISTINCT ResidentGroup, BalanceTypeID
    FROM Credits.ProductsPurposesBalanceGroups
)
select 
    p.TypeName as 'Purpose', 
    sum((case 
            when tr.CurrencyID = 417 
                 and rg.ResidentGroup IS NOT NULL 
               then tr.SumV 
               else 0 
         end)) as 'Pay417', 
    sum((case 
            when tr.CurrencyID = 840 
                 and rg.ResidentGroup IS NOT NULL 
               then tr.SumV 
               else 0 
         end)) as 'Pay840', 
      -- and it goes that way until BalanceTypeID = 16"""

from 
    dbo.Transactions as tr 
inner join  
    dbo.Accounts as acc_credit on tr.CreditAccountID = acc_credit.AccountNo
left join
    cteResGrp rg ON rg.ResidentGroup = acc_credit.BalanceGroup
                 AND (    (rg.BalanceTypeID = 1 AND tr.CurrencyID = 417)
                       OR (rg.BalanceTypeID = 2 AND tr.CurrencyID = 840)
                       OR ...
                     )
group by 
    p.TypeName 
order by 
    p.TypeName
```

See the following fidle for an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d580ae/3/1

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to select the lineitem first, then aggregate in a second pass. For example with a CTE:

```
--Lineitem
;WITH CTE AS (
select 
    p.TypeName as 'Purpose', 
         case 
            when tr.CurrencyID = 417 
                 and acc_credit.BalanceGroup in (select distinct ResidentGroup 
                                                 from Credits.ProductsPurposesBalanceGroups 
                                                 where BalanceTypeID = 1) 
               then tr.SumV 
               else 0 
         end as 'Pay417', 
         case 
            when tr.CurrencyID = 840 
                 and acc_credit.BalanceGroup in (select distinct ResidentGroup 
                                                 from Credits.ProductsPurposesBalanceGroups 
                                                 where BalanceTypeID = 2) 
               then tr.SumV 
               else 0 
         end as 'Pay840'
      -- and it goes that way until BalanceTypeID = 16"""

from 
    dbo.Transactions as tr 
inner join  
    dbo.Accounts as acc_credit on (tr.CreditAccountID = acc_credit.AccountNo)

.
.
.
) --End of CTE

--Aggregate lineitem
SELECT Purpose
      ,SUM(Pay417) AS [Pay417]
      ,SUM(Pay840) AS [Pay840]
  FROM CTE

group by 
    Purpose
order by 
    Purpose
```